# PHP Posting table needs info from user table

Tags: php, database, posting

I have a posting script where I need to put the post in a database but I need some data from another table to put into the post table, and I do not know how to do this, here's my code.

```
<body>

<?php

include ("include/header.html");

include ("include/sidebar.html");

?>
<div class="container">
<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  // Make sure the user is logged in before going any further.
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo '<p class="login">Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';
    exit();
  }
  else {
    echo('<p class="login">You are logged in as ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '. <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>');
  }

  // Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Grab the profile data from the POST
     $post1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['post1']));
    $error = false;

    // Update the profile data in the database
    if (!$error) {
      if (!empty($post1)) {
        // Only set the picture column if there is a new picture
        if (!empty($new_picture)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `ccp2_posts` (`post`) VALUES ('$post1')";
        }
        else {
          $query = "INSERT INTO `ccp2_posts` (`post`) VALUES ('$post1')";
        }
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        // Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>Your profile has been successfully updated. Would you like to <a href="viewprofile.php">view your profile</a>?</p>';

        mysqli_close($dbc);
        exit();
      }
      else {
        echo '<p class="error">You must enter all of the profile data (the picture is optional).</p>';
      }
    }
  } // End of check for form submission
  else {


    $error = false;

    // Grab the profile data from the database
    $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM ccp2_user WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);


    //DO I NEED TO PUT SOMETHING HERE TO SET A VARIABLE//
    //FOR THE FIRST_NAME AND LAST_NAME VALUES TO PUT IN//
    //THE DATABASE?//


           if (!empty($new_picture)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `ccp2_posts` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name')";
        }
        else {
          $query = "INSERT INTO `ccp2_posts` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name')";
        }
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    else {
      echo '<p class="error">There was a problem accessing your profile.</p>';
    }
  }

  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MM_MAXFILESIZE; ?>" />
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <label type="hidden" for="post1">Post:</label><br />
      <textarea rows="4"  name="post1" id="post1" cols="50">Post Here...</textarea><br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Profile" name="submit" />     
  </form>
   </div>
  <?php

include ("include/footer.html");

?>

</body> 
</html>
```

I need to take the first_name and last_name data from my ccp2_user table and put it in the first_name and last_name area in the ccp2_posts table. Help?

Comment: consider removing all but the pertinent code above. For example, authentication has got nothing to do with your question so, remove it and all other extraneous code to make it easier for us to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$row` variable should have the values of first_name and last_name:

`$first_name = $row['first_name'];`
`$last_name = $row['last_name'];`

Comment: What's in $row right after `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);` ? For debugging do a `var_dump($row);`, and if it doesn't have first/last names in it then `var_dump($_SESSION);` and check if the user id is actually in the session.

Comment: the only thing right now pertaining to $row is the things you told me to put there